# Error ")" Expected, but then Invalid token ")"?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I'm a bit of a beginner as far as C# goes and I literally have no idea what the error here is...

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Sancarn
{
    public class Form1 : Form 
    {
        public event EventHandler MessageHandler;
        public Message lastMessage;

        public string ptrToString(ptr As IntPtr)
        {
            return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
        }

        [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
            EventHandler handler = MessageHandler;
            lastMessage = m;
            if(null != MessageHandler) MessageHandler(this,EventArgs.Empty);
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to add this as a new type in powershell I get the following errors:

```
Add-Type : c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(11) : ) expected
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(10) : 
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(11) : >>>         public string ptrToString(ptr As IntPtr)
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(12) :         {
I...

Add-Type : c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(11) : Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(10) : 
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(11) : >>>         public string ptrToString(ptr As IntPtr)
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(12) :         {
...

Add-Type : c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(13) : Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(12) :         {
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(13) : >>>             return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(14) :         }
...

Add-Type : c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(13) : Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(12) :         {
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(13) : >>>             return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(14) :         }
...

Add-Type : c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(17) : Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(16) :         [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, 
Name="FullTrust")]
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(17) : >>>         protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(18) :             EventHandler handler = MessageHandler;
...

Add-Type : c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(26) : Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(25) :     }
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(26) : >>> }
...

Add-Type : c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(16) : The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(15) : 
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(16) : >>>         [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, 
Name="FullTrust")]
c:\Users\sancarn\AppData\Local\Temp\vqezctgu.0.cs(17) :         protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
...
```

So I'm not exactly sure what is going on here. From my perspective all of the brackets are paired correctly... I've figured out that if I comment out the `ptrToString` declaration, then the class compiles fine... So this has me believing that this declaration is somehow to blame for the error but... Either I am blind, missing something big, or there is nothing wrong with this statement...?

```
public string ptrToString(ptr As IntPtr){
    return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
}
```

Comment: In C#, you don't declare parameters with `As` - that is VB. I suggest you download [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) and play with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, you don't declare method parameters using `As` - that is VB.

Here is the fixed code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Sancarn {
    public class Form1 : Form {
        public event EventHandler MessageHandler;
        public Message lastMessage;

        public string ptrToString(System.IntPtr ptr) {
            return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
        }

        [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
            EventHandler handler = MessageHandler;
            lastMessage = m;
            if (null != MessageHandler) MessageHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```